# Docker client force Monolithic Upload

Tags: docker, docker-registry

According to [this](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/spec/api.md#monolithic-upload), docker have two upload systems.

1. Where the full layer uploads at once by PUT request(Monolithic Upload)
2. Chunked by PATCH request.

On my use case scenario I need to force the client to always push with Monolithic Upload. If a chunk request is received the registry must tell the client to fall back to Monolithic Upload and send the layer at once.

How can this be achieved ?